# R: What is the difference of the Lasso for variable selection between the packages glmnet and hdm

Tags: r, feature-selection, lasso, glmnet

For my PhD I use a Lasso approach in R for variable selection. Now, I used the package glmnet and also hdm. **What is the difference of the basic lasso estimator for logistic regression in these two packages?** I read the docs and also googled a lot but the only hint that I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013966/r-biglasso-results-dont-match-hdm-or-glmnet) which was not very helpful for my exact purpose.

The reason for asking is because my models converge if I use glmnet and they sometimes do not converge when I use hdm. That is why I assume that the difference is in the optimization function. Here is a minimal example:

```r
# Delete environment
rm(list = ls())

# Packages
library(glmnet)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loaded glmnet 4.1-4
library(hdm)

# get data
data = read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/gmXk0h2P", sep = ",", header = T)

# do the lasso
lasso_hdm = rlassologit(dep ~ ., data = data)
#> Warning: from glmnet C++ code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda value
#> not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned
#> Warning in getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames): an empty model has been returned;
#> probably a convergence issue
lasso_glm = glmnet(as.matrix(data[,!(names(data) %in% c("dep"))]), data$dep, family = "binomial")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Additionally, please find my sessionInfo:

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.39        magrittr_2.0.3    R.cache_0.15.0   
#>  [5] rlang_1.0.2       fastmap_1.1.0     fansi_1.0.3       stringr_1.4.0    
#>  [9] styler_1.7.0      highr_0.9         tools_4.2.0       xfun_0.31        
#> [13] R.oo_1.24.0       utf8_1.2.2        cli_3.3.0         withr_2.5.0      
#> [17] htmltools_0.5.2   ellipsis_0.3.2    yaml_2.3.5        digest_0.6.29    
#> [21] tibble_3.1.7      lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.5.1      purrr_0.3.4      
#> [25] R.utils_2.11.0    vctrs_0.4.1       fs_1.5.2          glue_1.6.2       
#> [29] evaluate_0.15     rmarkdown_2.14    reprex_2.0.1      stringi_1.7.6    
#> [33] compiler_4.2.0    pillar_1.7.0      R.methodsS3_1.8.1 pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In the end I am interested in the theory of both packages and maybe I find a good reason to stick to the glmnet package as this converges.

Thank you so much in advance!
For cross references: I also posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72426519/r-what-is-the-difference-of-the-lasso-for-variable-selection-between-the-packag) on stackoverflow. They sent me over to this forum.

Comment: In this data `indep1` and `indep2` are exactly the same `all.equal(data$indep1,data$indep2)`. I am guessing maybe possible simply initial conditions could cause the differences in results with that data (somewhat misleading to say that `glmnet` converges).

Comment: @Irazall did you ever figure out the answer? I am facing a similar issue in a research project right now but with running n LASSOs using enet and lars. The variables selected by them are different and I cannot figure out why exactly.

Comment: @Spencer No, unfortunately, I did not, but I stick to the glmnet as I think it is better maintained and more widely used.

Comment: @Irazall I understand that, but when I did use glmnet, it was returning all 30 of my candidate regressors when what I wanted to know was which of them the LASSO it implements was "selecting", so obviously, that just won't do.

Comment: @Spencer could it be that the LASSO just did not remove anything as your model has only a low explanatory power? This actually happened in my case.

Comment: That is of course theoretically possible when running any specific implantation of LASSO Regressions, but, that would not explain why the enet does select a subset of the 30 candidate regressors for every one of the 260,000 synthetic data sets, meanwhile when I run the replication script that uses glmnet on 5 or 10,000 of the data set instead, it selected the entire set of 30 candidate regressors for all 5k or 10k of the different data sets. In other words, functionally speaking, there is 0 perfect overlap!!